# How to prevent a click on an element just displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "show link" that when clicked displays a hidden < li > containing other links.

These links happen to display at the exact co-ordinates of the "show link".

When "show Link" is clicked, its event is fired, but then the link below also is triggered.

How to I stop the newly shown links from being clicked when I click "show link"?

Edit:
I am providing the code, but it may complicate the issue.  The setTapClickAction is to avoid the double click behaviour that you get using .on("touchstart click")

Inline script:

```
    ...
    let $m = $('<a href="#"/>').text('Show Link');
    $.setTapClickAction($m, function (el, e) {
      $('li.location').fadeIn( 1000);
      $(el).text("Show All").attr("href","https://example.com")
    });
    $('<p id="more-locations"/>').html($m).insertAfter(list);
    ...
```

main.js:

```
  // function to set the tap or click action on an element.
  // suggested usage:
  // $.setTapClickAction('.subscription_show_button', function(){
  //   $modalElement.modal('show');
  // });
  $.setTapClickAction = function (selector, actionFunction){
    if (typeof actionFunction !== 'function' ){
      console.log('No Action Function given. Function tapClickButton');
      return false;
    }
    let $obj;
    if (typeof selector === 'string'){
      $obj = $(selector);
    } else if (selector instanceof $) {
      $obj = selector;
    } else {
      console.log('No element for action: ' + selector);
      return false;
    }
    let touchmoved;
    $obj.on('click',function(e){
      actionFunction($(this), e);
      console.log("click fired by " + this);
    }).on('touchend',function (e) {
      if (touchmoved !== true) {
        actionFunction($(this), e);
      }
    }).on('touchstart', function () {
      $(this).off('click');
      touchmoved = false;
      console.log("touchstart fired by " + this);
    }).on('touchmove', function () {
      touchmoved = true;
    });
  };
```

edit2:

Here is a link to the production site. https://t.starstarmobile.com/5/SESSIONIDB10/quick2?phone=8887186545 click or tap the "find other centers near you"

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: `if(event.target !== theElement){/* do stuff then only */ }`

Comment: an upvote for this OP?

Comment: Hope event.stopPropagation() or event.stopImmediatePropagation will help you to prevent event bubbling.

Comment: maybe you could apply that click event listener to the window instead of the element then `event.preventDefault()` and use `event.target` to determine the element actually clicked?

Comment: tag me if this still isn't answered tomorrow and I'll try a jsfiddle.

Comment: Hope below snippet will help you. `on('touchstart', function (e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      touchmoved = false;
      console.log("touchstart fired by " + this);
    }).`

Comment: @Veeresh I tried your suggestion on my dev site, but it had no effect.  I am including a link to the production site in the description. It does not have your suggestion, but I wanted you to see what is happening.

Comment: @JonDeWitt  I was able to workaround the problem by adding e.preventdefault to  links clicked without an href value.

Answer (score 0):

So my answer to the problem was to use .preventDefault() on any links that did not have an href value. I also added namespaces so that the events could be modified multiple times.

```
    // function to set the tap or click action on an element.
    // suggested usage:
    // $.setTapClickAction('.subscription_show_button', function(){
    //   $subscriptionModal.modal('show');
    // });
    $.setTapClickAction = function (selector, actionFunction) {
      let $obj, touchmoved, hasHref;
      let namespace = "";
      if (typeof actionFunction !== 'function') {
        console.log('No Action Function given. Function tapClickButton');
        return false;
      }
      if (typeof selector === 'string') {
        $obj = $(selector);
        //set the name space
        namespace = selector.charAt(0) !== '.' ? '.' + selector : selector;
        // console.log("string selector", selector);
      } else if (selector instanceof $) {
        $obj = selector;
        // console.log("jquery Instance", selector);
      } else {
        console.log('No element for action:', selector);
        return false;
      }
      //look for valid href or exec e.preventDefault
      let href = $obj.attr("href");
      if (href !== '#' && href !== undefined) {
        hasHref = true;
        // console.log ("Href: " + href)
      }
      //remove previously set events
      $obj.off('click' + namespace);
      $obj.off('touchstart' + namespace);
      $obj.off('touchend' + namespace);
      $obj.off('touchmove' + namespace);

      //set events
      // console.log('namespace: '+ namespace);
      $obj.on('click' + namespace, function (e) {
        if (!hasHref) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        actionFunction($(this), e);
        // console.log("click fired by ", this);
      }).on('touchend' + namespace, function (e) {
        if (touchmoved !== true) {
          actionFunction($(this), e);
        }
      }).on('touchstart' + namespace, function (e) {
        if (!hasHref) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        $(this).off('click' + namespace);
        touchmoved = false;
        // console.log("touchstart fired by:", this, e.currentTarget.getAttribute("href"));
      }).on('touchmove' + namespace, function () {
        touchmoved = true;
      });
    };
```